# Cómo obtener la ruta real de un archivo en Android 10?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarinforms

estoy usando Xamarin Forms en VS2019 Y desarrollé una app que lee cierto tipo de archivo con extensión .PRX, una vez abre el archivo guarda su ruta en una BD local SqLite a modo de historial, eso funciona hasta Android 9 (Api 28), pero por requerimientos de cierto Plugin tuve que actualizar el target a Android 10 (Api 29) y empezaron los problemas, en este caso es que si bien en Android 9 la ruta era una ruta absoluta basada en el esquema interno de archivos del equipo, algo parecido a esto:

```
/storage/emulated/0/....
```

Ahora resulta que en Android 10, la ruta para el mismo archivo es:

```
content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D1%3Bdoc%3Dencoded%3D4LdCni%2FrOxCCjiz8
```

o

```
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/8
```

Y mi problema es que cuando quiero recuperar el archivo usando esa ruta que cargo desde la BD no funciona, simplemente no la encuentra, he leído **muchísimos** artículos y todos muestran como implementar una solución basada en FilesHelper pero es código que se aplica en Xamarin.Android (como [este código en GitHub](https://gist.github.com/IlyaLavrov97/a76063a49515764b60d5fba3ebbb2662)) y no se si lo uso mal o no se aplica a mi proyecto, ya que yo edito el código compartido y la versión en Android, iOS y UWP se compilan por si mismas, entonces no se como llamarlo o si realmente puedo hacerlo.

Entiendo que es un tema de seguridad que implementaron en Android 10, pero ya me he partido la cabeza mucho tiempo buscando como cargar un archivo cuya ruta tengo guardada con Android 10 y no me resulta.

Necesito POR FAVOR me indiquen como lograrlo pero desde Xamarin Forms, no desde Xamarin Android, y si ese resulta el caso me detallen como se hace de ese modo porque ya no encuentro donde más buscar.

Gracias.

Comment: No se que te sucederea, pero deberias usar DependencyService y de esa modo podes usar ese codigo de Xamarin.Android y llamarlo desde Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: Lo intenté, pero el código me pide el Context, le paso el Context de la App, del Activity... pero no funciona. Por ahora estoy copiando el archivo que abro a FileSystem.AppDataDirectory pero no es la mejor opción porque empiezo a llenar la memoria.

Comment: no se de este tema pero has probado y se puede colocar una ruta relativa? de este modo tal vez si puedas acceder.

Comment: No se puede, el problema es que Android 10 no permite las rutas absolutas, cuando seleccionas un archivo, la ruta que se registra en memoria es una especie de "acceso directo" nada relacionado a la ruta real y solo sirve esa vez, aunque la guardes no puedes volver a usar esa ruta otra vez..

Answer (score 0):

Has intentado localizar esa misma ruta en una subcarpeta?
EJ:

> content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D1%3Bdoc%3Dencoded%3D4LdCni%2FrOxCCjiz8

Eliminas "content://":

> com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D1%3Bdoc%3Dencoded%3D4LdCni%2FrOxCCjiz8

Ahora, esta ruta parece una ruta que se encuentra en:

> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/

Así que una posible solución (no estoy seguro al 100%) sería:

> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D1%3Bdoc%3Dencoded%3D4LdCni%2FrOxCCjiz8

Comment: Si, pero no es así como funciona, es una ruta "de fantasía" y ni siquiera es persistente, sino que cambia con el uso.